# Flexbox container with height 100% breaks layout on mobile but works on desktop browser at mobile size

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't find it.
When I check the page rendered from the below css and html on chrome or safari on iphone, the flexbox layout breaks and continues past the righthandside of the browser window.

But if I remove height:100% on the .container class in the CSS, the layout becomes stacked. Just like it is stacked without removing height:100% on the browser on my laptop if I set the window to mobile size.

So, on desktop browser set to mobile it works without any amends. But from my mobile, I have to untick height:100 percent.

I must be missing something very obvious here.

////// EDIT : I put the container class in there so I could stretch content to vertical bottom, if I drop the container class entirely, mobile works and it stacks just like it stacks on desktop at mobile size, if i don't remove the container class ////////

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

/*instead of transparent borders one could try calc*/
.column,
.columnB {
  border: 10px solid white;
}

/* Container for flexboxes */
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Create four equal columns */
.column {
  -webkit-box-flex: 25%;
  -ms-flex: 25%;
  flex: 25%;

  padding: 20px;
}

.rowB {
  height: 100%;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;

  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.columnB:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-box-flex: 30%;
  -ms-flex: 30%;
  flex: 30%;

  padding: 20px;
}

.columnB:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-box-flex: 70%;
  -ms-flex: 70%;
  flex: 70%;

  padding: 20px;
}

/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, 
go from four columns to two columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .column {
    -webkit-box-flex: 50%;
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 768px wide or less, 
make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .column {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .columnB {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 !important;
    -ms-flex: 1 !important;
    flex: 1 !important;
  }


  .row,
  .rowB {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
                <h2>Column 1</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
                <h2>Column 2</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
                <h2>Column 3</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
                <h2>Column 4</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowB">
            <div class="columnB" style="background-color:#949494;">
                <h2>Row 2 Column 1</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="columnB" style="background-color:#bbb;">
                <h2>Row 2 Column 2</h2>
                <p>Some text..</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It will be easier for the community to help you if you put the code in a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You can also add a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w2btL0pa/) to help people reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks, I've done so now. Use the full page mode and resize and if u then check from mobile you will see the grrrr issue. Thanks for the tip :)